# How overlay and increase height of panel in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

Need some direction with the creation of a control in WPF, the interface is like below:
The control would come before the image control.
The control contents are not fully displayed, if the user wants to view full details, user can click on the button on the control to make it expand.However it should overlay on the image below and not push it down.

| **_______Control________________**|
|
|
|**_______________________________**| <- this should over the image below

| **_____________Image____________**|
|
|
|
| **______________________________**| <- Image section

I have tried to expander control:
1. It shows or hides all the content.
2. Push down the image below.

Probably i would need to create custom control,which derives from ContentControl,
how would i add the expanding tray like capability with a higher zindex.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put both controls into a common grid, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <YourControl .../>
    <Image .../>
</Grid>
```

Then both your control and the image would cover the same region.

Furthermore, you could wrap your control into an expander:

```
<Grid>
    <Expander Header="Show details">
        <YourControl .../>
    </Expander>
    <Image .../>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me, I also had to set the zindex on the expander.